# url redirection with variables using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I´m trying to redirect from a domain to a second domain name with variables in the url and is needed to add text to the url:

www.example.**es**/sub/cart.php?a=add&pid=x

to

www.example.**com**/sub/cart.php?a=add&pid=x&**template=spain**

hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub/cart\.php$ http://www.example.com/sub/cart.php?template=spain [L,QSA,R]
```

Add those rules to the top of the htaccess file in the document root of the `www.example.es` domain.